# How to change default value of standard From picklist fields while sending mail from case

Tags: email, configuration, customization, email2case

My question is how can I change default value of 'From' standard pick list field using code?

So what I did is I have added below logic on 'Send Email' button:
`/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}&p3_lkid={!Case.Id}&p4_lkid={!Opportunity.OwnerId}&rtype=003&retURL=%2F{!Case.Id}&p26= support@example.com`

But when I am testing this logic it is showing me 3 values, 1st which is set in above, 2nd logged in user mail address and then 3rd is again `support@example.com`. I don't know from where this 3rd value is coming. Might be from email to case. But how can I show only 2 values here with default `support@example.com`?